# Restore database .bak file to azure elastic pool database from VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, database-restore, azure-elasticpool

Restore database .bak file to azure elastic pool database from VM

How to restore database .bak file to azure elastic pool databases directly, I used the option **"Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database"**  but every time creates a new database outside of the elastic pool.

We are looking for a solution to create a new database in an elastic pool only, any alternative methods we can achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure SQL Database does not currently support that customers use bak file as a restore to generate a new database on Azure SQL Database. The only method used to restore in Azure SQL Database is to import from BACPAC files by following this document :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-import?tabs=azure-powershell.

So according to the situation, you use  the option "Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database" then migrate the database to  azure elastic pool. Regarding how to migrate it, please refer to  https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoft-azure/sql-server/pooled/index.htm